# Qt C++ Parsing JSON nested data from API response using JsonDocument

Tags: c++, qt

I have the following JSON response read from an API, using `QJsonDocument`, and I'm trying to read the postal codes value:

```
{
  "data": {
   "website": "https://somesite.com/",
   "name": "SomeSite",
   "description": "description of the product",
   "techs": [
     "sitetech1",
     "sitetech2"
   ],
   "state": null,
   "city": null,
   "postal codes": [
   {
     "value": "123456",
   }
   ]
  }
}
```

With the following code I read the response:

```
QStringList postals;
QString jsonText = (QString)reply->readAll();
QJsonDocument jsonResponse = QJsonDocument::fromJson(jsonText.toUtf8());
QJsonObject jsonObject = jsonResponse.object();
QJsonArray jsonArray = jsonObject["data"].toArray();
if(jsonArray.isEmpty()) {
        qDebug() << "jsonArray is empty"; // this gets to here.
        return "empty";
    }
    foreach (const QJsonValue & value, jsonArray) {
        QJsonObject obj = value.toObject();
        QJsonArray arr = obj["postal codes"].toArray();
        foreach(const QJsonValue & value, arr) {
            postals.append(obj["value"].toString());
        }
    }
}
```

But it seems like the `jsonArray` is empty. Did I parse the JSON incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

"data" does not seem to be an array, so "toArray()" fails. Also, in the loop, you are looking for the key "value" inside the wrong object it seems. Also, there is a comma which shouldn't be there in the json.

Something like this maybe?

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "website": "https://somesite.com/",
      "name": "SomeSite",
      "description": "description of the product",
      "techs": [
        "sitetech1",
        "sitetech2"
      ],
      "state": null,
      "city": null,
      "postal codes": [
        {
          "value": "123456"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

code:

```
QString jsonText = f.readAll();
QJsonParseError error;
QJsonDocument jsonResponse = QJsonDocument::fromJson(jsonText.toUtf8(), &error);
if (error.error != QJsonParseError::NoError)
    qDebug() << "Error:" << error.errorString();

QJsonObject jsonObject = jsonResponse.object();


QJsonArray jsonArray = jsonObject["data"].toArray();
if (jsonArray.isEmpty()) {
    qDebug() << "jsonArray is empty"; // this gets to here.
    return -1;
}

for (const QJsonValue & value : jsonArray) {
    QJsonObject obj = value.toObject();
    QJsonArray arr = obj["postal codes"].toArray();
    for (const QJsonValue & value : arr) {
        postals.append(value["value"].toString());
        qDebug() << "val:" << value["value"].toString();
    }
}
```

output:

```
val: "123456"
```